# GPSID - Poll Driver V2.0

Tags: windows-mobile

On the page
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202066.aspx

If references something called "POLL Driver V2" however this is the only 
place I can see that talks about this.  I'm extermely interested in the 
`GPSSetDeviceParam: GPS_QUERY_FIX` call but after searching for about 2 hours 
on this, I couldn't find any information.

Can someone point me in the right direction on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MS, GPSID - Poll Driver v2.0 are not made available to ISV's in WM6.1.  They are evaluating including this in a future version of the OS.

My solution along the same lines was to create a Windows CE notification that fires at a predetermined interval.  Then when my app receives the notification, I set the power mode to "Unattended".  To make this work however you will need to set the power requirements in the registry for the GPDO to D0 when in the "Unattended" power mode.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\State\Unattended

gpd0: = 0

Using the SetPowerRequirement or SetDevicePower = D0 does not accomplish the same thing.